# kibana4 doesn't recognize my timestamp, ES is mapping it as a string

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, kibana

I want to push data I have in my hadoop cluster to ES and then visualize the hole thing in kibana4.
this is what I’ve done :
1)

```
CREATE TABLE xx(traffic_type_id INT, caller INT, time STRING, tranche_horaire INT, called INT, call_duration INT, code_type_trafic STRING, code_destination_trafic STRING, location_number STRING, id_offre INT, id_service INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t';
LOAD DATA INPATH ‘/user/hive/outt.csv’ OVERWRITE INTO TABLE xx;
```

---

2)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE esxx (caller INT, time STRING, tranche INT, called_number INT, duration INT, code_type STRING, code_destination STRING, location STRING, offre INT, service INT)
STORED BY ‘org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler’
TBLPROPERTIES(‘es.resource’ = ‘xx/xx’,
‘es.nodes’=’192.168.238.130:9200′,
‘es.mapping.names’ = ‘time:@timestamp’);
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE escdr SELECT s.caller, s.time, s.tranche_horaire, s.called, s.call_duration, s.code_type_trafic, s.code_destination_trafic, s.location_number, s.id_offre, s.id_service FROM xx s;
```

---

3)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE xx (
caller INT,
time TIMESTAMP,
tranche INT,
called_number INT,
duration INT,
code_type STRING,
code_destination STRING,
location STRING,
offre INT,
service INT)
STORED BY ‘org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler’
TBLPROPERTIES(‘es.resource’ = ‘xx/xx/’,
‘es.nodes’=’192.168.238.130:9200′,
‘es.mapping.names’ = ‘time:@timestamp’);
```

But Kibana doesn’t seem to recognize my timestamp “time”, ES keeps on mapping it as a string (the time field in my csv file is as so : exp : 01AUG2014:19:02:11 ! What should I do and change to let ES do the appropriate mapping and thus recognize my timestamp?

Best regards,

Omar,

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would convert this strange timestamp format to basic ISO8601 on the fly while importing, so that your timestamps look like 2014-08-01T19:02:11Z (or +HH:MM for whatever timezone you have your time in; I have no way to tell).

Comment: Would you be kind enough to tell me how to do so?